# entity framework data class

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I found a solution for my problem

```
   public class Employee
    {
        public int? Id { get; set; }
        public bool IsIdSelected { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }
        public bool IsNameSelected { get; set; }

        public string Address { get; set; }
        public bool IsAddressSelected { get; set; }
    }

        private void OnExportButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Now, concatinate all the selected cells
            var str = string.Empty;
            foreach (var emp in _collection)
            {
                if (emp.IsIdSelected)
                    str += string.Format("{0}, ", emp.Id);

                if (emp.IsNameSelected)
                    str += string.Format("{0}, ", emp.Name);

                if (emp.IsAddressSelected)
                    str += string.Format("{0}", emp.Address);

                str += "\n";
            }
            // Instead of displaying this message you could export these cells to Excel
            // in the format you need.
            MessageBox.Show(str);
        }
    }
}
```

But...

My class generate with entity contains this:

```
public partial class People
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Phone { get; set; }

    }
```

I can’t add bool fields to it because it breaks the logic and entity core does not allow me to do this.

How can I solve the problem?
Thanks.

Comment: Never concatenate a `string` in a loop. You should be using a `StringBuilder` here instead. Also, your question is not precisely clear as to what your problem is and what sort of solution you are seeking.

Comment: please make question clear

Answer (score 0):

i suggest that use ViewModel + automapper
you don't wana save IsSelected field to Data Storage so use ViewModel And Map it to DataModel and vice-versa.

Answer (score 0):

You can add whatever properties you want to your entities, if you want entity framework to ignore them completely then mark them with `[NotMapped]`.

This has been supported for ages.

Answer (score 0):

why you'd want to add bool field to the people class or what you intend to achieve from that is not explicitly stated but I'd tell you what I think.

1. If the point is to add extra properties to the people class, just do it!

   ```
   public partial class People

   {

   public int Id { get; set; }

   public int IsIdSelected { get; set; }

   public string Name { get; set; }

   public int IsNameSelected { get; set; }

   public string Phone { get; set; }

   public int IsPhoneSelected { get; set; }

   //you can let me know what error you are getting from adding this properties!!

   }
   ```
2. I am guessing you want to replicate what you did for employee in people class, just do that!

   ```
    private void OnExportButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Now, concatinate all the selected cells
        var str = string.Empty;
        foreach (var ppl in _collection)
        {
            if (ppl.IsIdSelected)
                str += string.Format("{0}, ", ppl.Id);

            if (ppl.IsNameSelected)
                str += string.Format("{0}, ", ppl.Name);

            if (ppl.IsPhoneSelected)
                str += string.Format("{0}", ppl.Phone);

            str += "\n";
        }
        // Instead of displaying this message you could export these cells to Excel
        // in the format you need.
        MessageBox.Show(str);
    }
   ```
3. If "My class generate with entity" means you are generating the entity, it means that you very likely using database first and you are using ADO-EDMX file to generate your entitis base on the tables in the database. what that means is that you should add those properties as columns is the "People" table and then re-generate the entities, and you'd have your added properties.
4. If code first, add the properties and run the migration command

add-migration addedBoolProps
update-database

...whatever the case is, just state it explicitly.